# (JavaScript) .push is not a function

Tags: javascript

The function uses an iCal parser which returns future events from an .ics file. eventsParser variable contains all those events. Then I have to push them into the events Array for display. But when I run it I'm getting this error. Im trying to figure out with my limited js knowladge but no luck. I also checked a couple of the same issue here on StacOverflow, but nothing really helped me.

```
function LoadEvents() {
            var events = [];
            var eventsParser = [];
            var ical_file = 'js/sample.ics';

            new ical_parser(ical_file, function(cal){
                //When ical parser has loaded file
                //get future events
                eventsParser = cal.getFutureEvents();
                //console.log(events);
                eventsParser.forEach(function(events){
                    events.push({
                        title: event.SUMMARY,
                        startTime: event.start_time,
                        endTime: event.end_time,
                        allDay: false
                    });
                });
            });
            console.log(events);
            return events;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your foreach callback Is re-declaring an events variable.

Comment: You've named the parameter for your inner function `events` (looks to be a typo - voting as such) - it's using that instead of your outer scoped `events = []` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there was a small typo in following line: `eventsParser.forEach(function(event){}`. You can't use two, same named arguments. Function tried to push elements inside argument, not into the `events` array.

Try following code:

```js
function LoadEvents() {
  var events = [];
  var eventsParser = [];
  var ical_file = 'js/sample.ics';

  new ical_parser(ical_file, function(cal) {
    //When ical parser has loaded file
    //get future events
    eventsParser = cal.getFutureEvents();
    //console.log(events);
    eventsParser.forEach(function(event) {
      events.push({
        title: event.SUMMARY,
        startTime: event.start_time,
        endTime: event.end_time,
        allDay: false
      });
    });
  });
  console.log(events);
  return events;
}
```

Comment: @Ryad It's fixed.

Comment: So true.Thanks @Kinduser. I dont know how but Im always stuck on these silly mistakes.